# How is a PMOS transistor used as a switch?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches, analog, vlsi

I am trying to understand switching behaviour of PMOS transistor and how exactly it passes a bad `0` value. I'm getting confused with the notation.

More specifically, when the PMOS is on and \$V_{in}=0\,\textrm{V}\$, why does \$ V_{out} = V_{DD} - |V_{tp}| \$?

For NMOS, I apply the equations as following when the NMOS is on and the input is high,
$$ V_{gs(min)} = V_{tn} = V_{DD} - V_{out}$$
which implies:
$$ V_{out(max)} = V_{dd} - V_{tn} $$
For PMOS however, I have:
$$ V_{gs(max)} = V_{tp} $$
Now when I rewrite LHS as:
$$ V_g - V_{s(min)} = V_{tp} $$
Since \$ V_g = 0 \$, I get this weird result for \$ V_s \$.

How do I relate \$ V_s \$ to the output?

Video link for reference: https://youtu.be/z2yqmHClVO8?list=PLB3F0FC99B5D89571&t=1457

Comment: Hit the [edit] link and add the URL for the video in case anyone wants to get the context.

Comment: Do you understand how an NMOS operates as a switch?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, and I am able to derive it myself too. I just don't seem to get it for PMOS. When I apply the PMOS equations myself, I get a different result.

Comment: So, show your NMOS derivations in your question and explain that you can't seem to be able to repeat for PMOS.

Comment: @Andyaka Edited..

Comment: Exactly the same as an NMOS but upside down.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to understand why PMOS passes a bad `0` value, take a look at the circuit below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFw5xk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we assume \$ V_{in} = 0\,\textrm{V} \$ and \$ V_{DD} = 0\,\textrm{V} \$ and the capacitor has an initial voltage of \$ 5\;\textrm{V} \$:

The pin connected to the capacitor is effectively the source, because it has the higher voltage, therefore drain is the pin connected to \$ V_{DD} \$.

Let's also assume that \$ V_{tp} = -1\,\textrm{V} \$.  Because,
$$ V_{S} - V_{G} > |V_{tp}| $$
the PMOS is turned ON and there is a path for the capacitor to discharge.

This continues until the capacitor's voltage reaches \$ |V_{tp}| \$, where conduction slows and eventually ceases.

Comment: This answer is confusing me. If the capacitor is at 5V, the body diode of the PMOS device would be forward biased, and the capacitor would quickly discharge with high current until it goes below about 0.7V. And the capacitor is connected to the DRAIN of M1, so it should not be called SOURCE.